# Verificar conexão a cada instante

Tags: android

É o seguinte, estou criando app que depende da conexão com a internet para a maioria dos serviços. Para torna-lo mais dinâmico, eu pensei em fazer algo parecido com o app do YouTube. No app do youtube ele avisa quase instantaneamente que o aplicativo está sem conexão. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dei uma pesquisada geral e tentei fazer uso de `Threads` em duas formas:

**1. Executor + Runnable**

```
      class ThreadInfinity implements Executor {

            @Override
           public void execute(@NonNull Runnable r) {

                while (true) {
                    r.run();
                }

            }
        }

        Thread r = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                    if (manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Você está conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    } else {

                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Você está desconectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        ThreadInfinity t = new ThreadInfinity();
        t.execute(r);
```

**2. AsyncTask**

```
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        final ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        class TheadInfinity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                while (true)
                    try {
                        if (manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Você está conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        } else {

                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Você está desconectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        }
                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
            }
        }

        TheadInfinity t = new TheadInfinity();
        t.doInBackground();
```

Ambas não travam o aplicativo mas a tela fica em branco. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que o modo correto não é com Thread. Deve haver algum listener que possa ser usado. Porém eu não encontrei em lugar algum "nas internet".

## Dúvida

Como posso fazer isso? =)

Comment: Cara, o android tem os [`Broadcasts`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html), que são notificações que o proprio sistema operacional para alguns eventos. No seu caso, acredito que deva usar o intent filter para a ação `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`. [No SO já tem uma resposta sobre isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app). Se não me engano, houveram alterações no Android 8 e alguns desses eventos não estão mais disponíveis, vale a pena consultar.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza vou dar uma olhada.. obrigado

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza dei uma olhada. E parece que é isso mesmo. Vou fazer uns testes amanha. De qualquer forma, seria legal vc formular uma resposta aqui sobre isso. Visto que poderia ajudar quem procurar por isso. Eu, nem sabia que existia. =)

Comment: Realmente é um conteúdo muito interessante. Mas infelizmente não domino [tag:java] nem desenvolvimento [tag:android] nativo para postar algo realmente útil sem despender mais tempo do que gostaria. Fica a dica para quem tiver mais disponibilidade ou você mesmo, caso encontre seu caminho usando essa solução =)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza eu tbm nao domino. kkkk vamos deixar pros especialistas entao.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu uso essa classe em meus projetos:

```
public class ConexaoInternet extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public enum TipoConexao {TIPO_NAO_CONECTADO,TIPO_WIFI, TIPO_MOBILE};

    private  TipoConexao tipoConexaoATUAL = TipoConexao.TIPO_NAO_CONECTADO; //cache
    private boolean inicializou = false;

    private TipoConexao getStatusConexao(Context context) {
        synchronized (tipoConexaoATUAL){
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            tipoConexaoATUAL = TipoConexao.TIPO_NAO_CONECTADO;

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm==null ? null : cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (null != activeNetwork) {
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    tipoConexaoATUAL = TipoConexao.TIPO_WIFI;
                }
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                    tipoConexaoATUAL = TipoConexao.TIPO_MOBILE;
                }
            }

            return tipoConexaoATUAL;
        }
    }

    public TipoConexao getTipoConexaoAtual(Context context){
        if(!inicializou){
            inicializou = true;
            return getStatusConexao(context);
        }
        return tipoConexaoATUAL;
    }

    public interface IOnMudarEstadoConexao{
        void onMudar(TipoConexao tipoConexao);
    }
    private ArrayList<IOnMudarEstadoConexao> onMudarEstadoConexoesListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addOnMudarEstadoConexao(IOnMudarEstadoConexao t){
        onMudarEstadoConexoesListeners.add(t);
    }
    public void removeOnMudarEstadoConexao(IOnMudarEstadoConexao t){
        onMudarEstadoConexoesListeners.remove(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TipoConexao tipo = getStatusConexao(context);

        for(IOnMudarEstadoConexao o : onMudarEstadoConexoesListeners){
            o.onMudar(tipo);
        }

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(connectivityManager!=null){
                for (Network net : connectivityManager.getAllNetworks()) {
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(net);
                    if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(net);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

É necessário registrar quando a Activity for criada

```
private ConexaoInternet conexaoInternet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
    conexaoInternet = new ConexaoInternet();
    registerReceiver(conexaoInternet,intentFilter);
```

É necessário remover quando a activity for destruída

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(conexaoInternet);
}
```

Exemplo:
Para adicionar um listener toda vez que o dispositivo mudar a sua conexão

```
conexaoInternet.addOnMudarEstadoConexao(
    new ConexaoInternet.IOnMudarEstadoConexao() {
        @Override
        public void onMudar(ConexaoInternet.TipoConexao tipoConexao) {
            if(tipoConexao == ConexaoInternet.TipoConexao.TIPO_MOBILE ||
                            tipoConexao == ConexaoInternet.TipoConexao.TIPO_WIFI){

                //faça algo quando a conexão for alterada para 3g/wifi

            }else if(tipoConexao == ConexaoInternet.TipoConexao.TIPO_NAO_CONECTADO){

               //faça algo quando o dispositivo perder conexão

            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Legal! Vou testar seu código amanha. Obrigado!

Comment: Qualquer coisa dá um toque

Comment: Então amigo... Não funciona.

Comment: Coloquei um toast no "//faça algo quando a conexão for alterada para 3g/wifi" e no "//faça algo quando o dispositivo perder conexão"

Comment: E ele não gera erro algum.

Comment: Coloquei o `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>` no manifest

Comment: Funcionou! Esqueci de colocar `.show()` no Toast... kkkkkk valeu!

Comment: Que bom que ajudei :)

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Fez diferença o `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>` ou não ?

Comment: @DigaoParceiro ele irá verificar conexão de rede (3G/WIFI) ou internet ?

Comment: @RBZ ele verifica o tipo de conexão através das constantes. Mas eu adaptei para ser a mesma coisa. Porque no meu app não faz diferença. Mas imagine que tem coisas que é melhor fazer apenas através do wifi para não consumir muitos dados do usuário.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho eu estava com um problema desse, em que PRECISAVA identificar independente da rede, se há conexão com a internet. Se você tiver isso e puder me passar de alguma forma, agradeço demais, ou até o link. :]

Comment: @RBZ o seu caso é parecido com o meu, certo?

Comment: @RBZ sobre ter que inserir `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>` não fez diferença. Com ou sem funcionou. Mas vou pesquisar pois pode ser que sem isso, em versões anteriores pode não funcionar.

Comment: Essa linha verifica o tipo de internet e se há conexao. ` if(tipoConexao == ConexaoInternet.TipoConexao.TIPO_MOBILE ||
                            tipoConexao == ConexaoInternet.TipoConexao.TIPO_WIFI){ ...`

Comment: @RBZ eu conversei com o amigo aqui embaixo (gaspar). Ele disse que você precisa colocar `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>` para novas activitys. Apenas a main activity dá suporte para isso sem precisar inserir essa linha. Tinha esquecido de comentar isso, mas antes tarde do que nunca. Dá uma olhada na conversa. Abraço!

Comment: @AndreiCoelho valeu meu querido ! Vou olhar sim ! Obrigado por lembrar ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você precisa mapear uma **action** no AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
```

Então, vai ser possível criar um **receiver** para que você tenha uma ação a fazer quando o tipo de conexão mudar:

```
public class ConnectionChanged extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String ACTION_CONN_CHANGED = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_CONN_CHANGED)) {

            //TODO SEU CODIGO
        }
    }
}
```

E fazer como o @DigaoParceiro disse, verifique qual o tipo de conexão através de uma modelagem e tomar uma segunda ação para cada tipo de conexão.

```
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

Mais detalhes na documentação do Android: [Determinar e monitorar o status da conectividade](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

Comment: Obrigado. Agregou bastante.

Comment: Deixa eu te falar... Eu testei sem o `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>` e funcionou. Porque é importante colocar essa linha no manifest?

Comment: na verdade o `<action>` informado é um action já existente na biblioteca do android, então não precisou declarar o action no Mainfest, porém se você utilizar um **action** customizado é necessário declarar ele no mainfest antes. Você poderia ter um `<action android:name="MINHA_ACAO" />` e usar  para todo o projeto como por exemplo `intent.getAction().equals(MINHA_ACAO)`

Comment: Entendi. E se houver mais de um action eu teria que inserir nos outros actions?

Comment: sim, cada action **customizado** deve ser declarado no mainfest, se o action faz parte da biblioteca android, como o `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` não é necessário, como é o caso desse uso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11008893/3681565)

Comment: Valeu gaspar! Obrigado!

Comment: Valeu guerreiro! Por nada